# Google App Engine Cache List in Session Variable

Tags: java, google-app-engine, session

I have a question about Google App Engine java implementation.  I have been trying to port over an application to google app engine from mysql/tomcat.  I have changed and tested most of the code on the google app engine local environment.  The application works on the local google app engine but when it is deployed it does not work.  I have narrowed the problem down to a variable that caches information in a list that is stored in a session variable.  Is this a prohibited action in Google app engine, and if so does anyone have a work around.  I really don't want to be hitting the datastore unless this list is changed.

thanks,

Comment: I'm using Java to build an application for GAE and i notice that our application can be somehow undeployed (maybe due to lack of usage) and automatic deployed when needed. Maybe the session variable is not being preserved and you should considered in persisting it in DB of file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, because sessions are backed by the datastore you need to call `session.setAttribute` everytime you change anything in the object.